# Как блокировать подключение конкретного IP к серверу:25?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, sendmail, postfix

В логах появилась подозрительная активность:

```
warning: unknown[141.98.81.189]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
disconnect from unknown[141.98.81.189] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
```

И так каждые 3 секунды. 
Установлен Почтовый сервер Postfix.
Как жестко блокировать IP еще на стадии подключения к серверу?

Comment: пробовали iptables?

Comment: спасибо. Но они меняют IP. Может стоит установить Fail2ban?

Comment: в таком случае конечно стоит...

Comment: Fat-Zer, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

```
....

    sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 141.98.81.189 --dport 25 -j DROP
```

Посмотреть все правила можно командой:

```
      sudo iptables -n -L -v --line-numbers
```

или

```
sudo ufw deny proto tcp from 41.98.81.189 to any port 25
```

- +Fail2ban